# Preserving aliases over OSX ssh rsync

Tags: macos, ssh, osx-yosemite, rsync

I'm having a devil of a time preserving aliases with rsync over ssh on OSX (Yosemite)

```
rsync -av -e ssh me@N.N.N.N:/Users/me/stuff/ /Users/me/stuff
```

does not preserve aliases. It makes an alias on the destination... but it doesn't point to the original file (on the destination). Firing up a Finder window, turning on File Sharing on the source, and drag and dropping preserves aliases, but that's the only way I've figured out how to do this so far, and I would prefer a non-GUI solution. Would something besides rsync work over ssh?

I've tried both native OSX rsync as well as Homebrew's.

Thanks super in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-E` (or `-X` on rsync v3) option. Alias files include resource forks. The `-E` option is documented as:

> ```
>   -E, --extended-attributes
>           Apple specific option  to  copy  extended  attributes,  resource
>           forks,  and  ACLs.   Requires at least Mac OS X 10.4 or suitably
>           patched rsync.
> ```

Comment: Many thanks. For those who may come across this, as far as I can tell, the Homebrew version of rsync 3.1.1 does **not** preserve aliases with this flag. I tested it with Homebrew rsync (-avE) and it created the same blank files I had originally. Yosemite's native /usr/bin/rsync 2.6.9 did, however, work.