# How can I preserve aliases when copying folders on the command line in OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, rsync, cp

I'm trying to write a personal backup command-line utility on OSX. Let's say I have two folders:

```
foo/bar/
foo/baz/
```

`foo/bar` contains, among other things, OSX aliases to files in `foo/baz`:

```
foo/bar/file_alias@ -> foo/baz/file
```

I want to copy both `foo/bar` and `foo/baz` to an external hard drive, but for various reasons I do *not* just want to copy the entire folder `foo`. I can't figure out a way to copy these folders separately and make the aliases come out right in the end:

- `cp -r foo/bar /external_hd/foo/bar` follows the aliases, replacing them with the original files.
- `cp -R foo/bar /external_hd/foo/bar` preserves the aliases, but they (not surprisingly) continue to point to the original files (e.g. `foo/baz/file`, not `external_hd/foo/baz/file`).
- `rsync -avE foo/bar /external_hd/foo/bar` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428806/preserving-aliases-over-osx-ssh-rsync)) seems to do the same thing as `cp -R`.

Is there any way to accomplish this without copying the entire parent folder `foo`?

Comment: What you call "alias" is actually called symbolic link or symlink for short. Mac uses aliases too but its something else. So to get proper answers symbolic links and relink is what you should ask about.

Comment: You need to be clearer about the actual content of the symbolic link. For example, you show `foo/bar/file_alias@ -> foo/baz/file`, but that would point to `foo/bar/foo/baz/file`, not `foo/baz/file` where `baz` is a sibling of `bar`. So, are your symlinks relative with `../..` and the like, or are they absolute, like `/path/to/foo/baz/file`?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way where you can automatically copy folders and relink symbolic links to a new destination without some manual intervention. If you know the new paths its quite simple to script, though.

For your specific example; the following should do the trick to relink:

```
cd /external_hd/foo
find . -type l | while read x; do y=$(readlink "$x" | sed s'|/foo|/external_hd/foo|'); ln -sf "$y" "$x";done
```

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` will get you close, the command:

```
rsync -avHER --safe-links foo/{bar,baz} /external_hd/
```

will copy the two folders, preserve "safe" relative symlinks between, and ignore "unsafe" symlinks - those that *may* reference files outside of the copied tree. Change it to:

```
rsync -avHER --copy-unsafe-links foo/{bar,baz} /external_hd/
```

and "safe" relative symlinks are preserve and "unsafe" symlinks are replaced by their destination.

If you only have "safe" relative symlinks the first option will do, the second option may do if some extra copying is OK.

**However**, the definition of "safe" is over-restrictive. Any absolute symlink is "unsafe" even if its target is within the copied tree. Furthermore even a relative link which goes too far towards the root, or maybe is just too complicated, is also "unsafe".

If you need to fix this it should be possible, as the above options show `rsync` is pretty close to what you need and the source code is available from [Apple's Open Source site](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/rsync/). Examine the code around the options `--links`, `--copy-links`, `--copy-unsafe-links` & `unsafe-links` and you may find fixing the definition of "safe" is fairly easy (and you can re-write the symlinks to use the shortest possible relative path at the same time).

HTH

Comment: Thanks @CRD -- I think you've pointed me in the right direction. I'm still having trouble getting the symlinks in `external_hd/foo/bar` to point to files in `external_hd/foo/baz` though. `--copy-links`, `--copy-unsafe-links`, and `--safe-links` seem to transform the links to their referents; `--links` preserves them but they point to the original targets (not the ones on `external_hd`. I'll keep experimenting.